# Is there a word for "under one's real name?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means an object of creation was made under the given name of the person who created it, as opposed to a moniker.

In this case, I'm a musician who used to release music under a moniker and now I'm switching to use my given name as the "artist."  I'd like if there was a construction parallel to when a musician breaks away from a band and starts a "solo" career.

> Though he's still recording with his decades long band Wilco, lead singer Jeff Tweedy released his first **solo** album Tuesday.

(I'm not Jeff Tweedy.)

So in this case the parallel construction I'd love would be:

> Three years after releasing his last album as Fakename Jones, John Smith released his first ____ album Tuesday.

I haven't been able to find a word that works quite this way.  In my research, the closest I've been able to locate is "eponymous," meaning, "(of a thing) named after a particular person." And it's not quite close enough to mean even remotely the same thing, unfortunately.

A compound word or phrase would be acceptable, but the purpose of seeking a word or phrase that functions this way is to achieve as much elegance as possible.

Comment: **sans-pseudonym** might be a good word, not common but a clear enough meaning. I have a tendency to place it after "album" and use it as an adverb though.

Comment: “Under his own name” is often used for this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no word specific for this, because it's publishing something under an alias that's the exception to the rule. It's normal that people will publish under their own name, so it's only the exception that gets special attention.

However, a generic way of saying this could be **self-identified**:

> Three years after releasing his last album as Fakename Jones, John Smith released his first *self-identified* album Tuesday.

---

Note that this could be open to misinterpretation, making it seem as if it's the *album* identifying itself rather than the singer. However, the context should make it clear what's actually meant.

Answer (score 1):

> Three years after releasing his last album as Fakename Jones, John
>   Smith released his first album signed by his real name.

Or

> Three years after releasing his last album as Fakename Jones, John
>   Smith released his first album under his real name.

Answer (score -1):

The creation in question is ***attributable*** (to you), unlike your earlier (similar) creations.

> Three years after releasing his last album as Fakename Jones, John
>   Smith released his first ***attributable*** album Tuesday.

ODO/lexico:

> **[attributable](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/attributable)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** (often attributable to) (of a work or remark) able to be ascribed to a particular author, artist, or speaker.
>   ‘some 50
>   liturgical works by or attributable to him have survived’
>   ‘this may be
>   Leonardo 's earliest securely attributable painting’

Comment: *Attributable* refers more to whether other people know the origin, not whether something was labeled as such. Note the "works by or attributable to him," which suggests that works attributable to the artist are not so clearly *by* him but that, after some investigation, people (scholars?) attribute it to him.